# Openpyxl sum of rows and loops

Tags: python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

Im new to openpyxl and python so I am looking for some help on my project.
I am using openpyxl on python and I want to sum the rows until they reach a certain number. After reaching that certain number, it would paste the sum on the cell next to it. Then, the loop would skip all the rows that have been added and go on to the cell and do the sum.

To give an idea of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Edit1: I am stuck on the list index out of range

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import statistics

wb=load_workbook('Algorand.xlsx')
sheet=wb.active
testlist = []

for row in list(sheet.columns)[0]:
testlist= testlist + [row.value]

print(testlist)
avg=statistics.mean(testlist)
std=statistics.stdev(testlist)
target=avg+2*std
length=len(testlist)

for i in range(0,length-2):
   if testlist[i]<target:
   sum= testlist[i]+testlist[i+1]
   print(f"firstsum:{sum}")
   sheet.cell(row=i + 1, column=3, value=sum)

     if sum<target:
    next=i+2
    sum=sum+testlist[next]
    print(f"secsum:{sum}")
    sheet.cell(row=i + 1, column=3, value=sum)

        if sum<target:
        next = next + 1
        sum = sum + testlist[next]
        #next=i
        print(f"thirdsum:{sum}")
        sheet.cell(row=i + 1, column=3, value=sum)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi Charlie, i have updated my what I have in the post above

Comment: I can't really read that code but it looks too complicated and doing more than what you say it should.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to index the input place (row increasing, col=1) in a for loop

You need a sum variable to record the total added, it can be declared as 0 before the loop.

Then for each turn you add the read value to it, and then compare the condition.
If not breached, `continue` but if breached, write the sum next to it and then flash the sum back to 0.